# How to generalize sequence based models with 100k data samples?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, sequence, prediction

We have a dataset with over 400k unique users and their visiting days of a year in the website in sequence as shown in following. Value can vary between 1 and 365.

```
{
U1:[3,6,28,57,128,129,247,289,...],
U2:[18,77,81,179,340,...],
U3:[192,195,289,298,310,376,...],
U4:[93],
...
...
U400k:[54,97,164,167,250,...]
}
```

We have similar dataset for four years. We want to predict for individual user that what will be the next day of the year the user may likely to visit the website again. I was thinking about how to generalize sequence based model; but any other idea is welcome. So anyone having any idea about how we can go with this problem?

Comment: This is too broad. What have you tried codewise, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: We are stuck in finding right approach for this problem. We were initially thinking about sequence based model with days gap from the sequence shown above.

Comment: You can include more feature to the dataset from day of year like Season, Month, Weekday/weekend, Holiday. This can help in identifying trend among users.

Answer (score 0):

1) One way could be to categorize/cluster your data and do analysis at group level. ( Dymanic time series warping or clustering techniques).

If you want to have analysis at user level, then build all 100K time series.

2) I feel based on the data you have,  it's not possible to predict'what will be the day when user will come on site. You can forcast visits for next year by time series algos. Then use number of visit to when he might come on site.

3) you can also try Facebook's prophet model for time series forecasting esp build for forecasting visits on site.

https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2017/05/facebooks-phophet-model-for-forecasting.html